# Analysis of difference between actual and modelled time series data

Tags: statistics

I have 2 time series data sets, one comes from real data readings and another one is built by a model (The model has nothing to do with statistics). I calibrate the model based on the real data defined on some range and when I'm happy with the results I let it predict future real values.

My goal is now to determine whether the error term (Actual - Modelled) is significant enough and put it on a 0 - 1 scale (Where 0 means the error is the same or smaller than in calibration and 1 means the error is very large).

The problem is I don't know how to keep track of how good my model is in predicting the real data. I was thinking of finding the errors from the training set (during calibration) and use KS test to find a probability of whether new error term belong to the initial distribution of errors.
But it doesn't help if the real error is zero and my estimated distribution  doesn't take it into account i.e. the model predicted actual data better than during calibration.

I'm also not sure I can make a use of Central Limit as I don't think the error terms are i.i.d variables due to time series nature of data (correct me if I'm wrong)

I would appreciate if you can provide a hint or a reading on how to perform an analysis on difference between modelled and actual data.

Thanks in advance.

[Data (training period)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iJQkk.png)

Comment: So you have a lot of real data point from training and a lot of model data points. If your error is equally distributed, you should see a normal distribution in the error terms, right? (if not: why not?)

Comment: @Dirk, there are some outliers in the real data, resulting in large errors. If I resample errors to daily taken a median as a statistic, then it does follow a normal distribution (neither Pearson nor AD test reject H0), but I don't know how to account for a zero term (sample's mean is not zero)